# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed when installing a package

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to install a bunch of dependencies from the `requirements.txt` file of a cloned Django project. However, when it's trying to install one of them, `vobject-0.8.1c` the following error is displayed and none of the dependencies are installed:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-n_0xlr\vobject\

This is how I am trying to install these packages:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I have spent hours trying to solve this problem. All the issues I see about it suggest installing or upgrading `setuptools` and `ez_setup`. I have done that and I still get the error, so the project keeps having a ton of missing dependencies.

I am on Windows.

What can I do? How can I install these dependencies?

Comment: have you enough space on your C: drive? (just checking, don't take it the wrong way). When I have such problems, I usually install FileMon/ProcessMonitor to figure out why the process has crashed. Works well for I/O errors.

Comment: Since you mentioned pip, why aren't you using it?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes I do

Comment: @spectras I never said I am not using `pip`

Comment: So you did  `pip install -r requirements.txt` successfully and are stuck after, or it failed in the middle and that's what you are trying to fix?

Comment: It failed in the middle and I am trying to fix that.

Comment: It looks `vobject` is a pure python package, so that cannot be an issue about compiling. It's fairly simple as well. But it does have a dependency on `python-dateutil` and `six`. I guess you could try either to install dependencies manually and see if this goes well, narrowing it down to `vobject` or either dependency. Or you could try to install a newer version of `vobject` and hope the project you're trying to run will work with it.

Comment: How did you see the dependecies? I can only find the most recent version of `vobject`. Anyway, I manually installed `python-dateutil` and `six` and then tried installing `vobject 0.8.1c` and it still fails to install, either manually (`pip install vobject==0.8.1.c`) or through the `requirements.txt`file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `0.8.2`. It's first pip-installable version. All files is the same as in `0.8.1c` version, except:

**base.py**

```
286a287,288
>         for k,v in self.params.items():
>             self.params[k] = copy.copy(v)
630,631c632,633
<     def __init__(self, message, lineNumber=None):
<         self.message = message
---
>     def __init__(self, msg, lineNumber=None):
>         self.msg = msg
637c639
<                    (self.lineNumber, self.message)
---
>                    (self.lineNumber, self.msg)
639c641
<             return repr(self.message)
---
>             return repr(self.msg)
956c958,960
<         for key, paramvals in obj.params.iteritems():
---
>         keys = sorted(obj.params.iterkeys())
>         for key in keys:
>             paramvals = obj.params[key]
```

and **icalendar.py**

```
428a429,440
>                         
>                         # RFC2445 actually states that UNTIL must be a UTC value. Whilst the
>                         # changes above work OK, one problem case is if DTSTART is floating but
>                         # UNTIL is properly specified as UTC (or with a TZID). In that case dateutil
>                         # will fail datetime comparisons. There is no easy solution to this as
>                         # there is no obvious timezone (at this point) to do proper floating time
>                         # offset compisons. The best we can do is treat the UNTIL value as floating.
>                         # This could mean incorrect determination of the last instance. The better
>                         # solution here is to encourage clients to use COUNT rather than UNTIL
>                         # when DTSTART is floating.
>                         if dtstart.tzinfo is None:
>                             until = until.replace(tzinfo=None)
476c488
<             if hasattr(self.contents, name):
---
>             if name in self.contents:
```

There should be no problems with the change of version.